# Convert from url body request to UTF-8

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, request, cheerio

First all, english isn´t my native language. I hope that you can understand me.

I have an issue when I try to scrape a URL using the cheerio package. The issue is that when I get the data value, I end up with symbols such as `Manuel Aristar�n`. I want to scape this special character and end up with the correct accented character such as `Manuel Aristarán`. This data is stored in json.

Everything works fine, the only issue is the special characters.

I'm running the scraper using a route built with iron-router. Maybe I must to set a header for encoding the strings, really i don’t know. I would thanks you for any advice and help.

This is the code that I run for extract and store the info:

```
Router.route('/scraper/', function(){
  this.response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' );
  this.response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE' );
  this.response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, x-request-metadata' );
  this.response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true );

  var url = 'https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=LINI0EUAAAAJ';
  request(url, async function(error, response, html){

    console.log(html);

    if(!error){
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);

      var autor;

      var json_pre = {  
                        autor : ""
                     };

      $('#gsc_prf_in').filter(function(){
        var data = $(this);
        autor = data.text().trim();
        json_pre.autor = autor;
      })

    }
    console.log(json_final);
  })

}, {where : "server"});
```

.

```
//expected output: {  
              autor : "Manuel Aristarán"
          };

//real output: {  
              autor : "Manuel Aristar�n"
          };
```

The original page I am scraping has header charset = utf-8, but when I use the request (url, response, html) method. This html when I show it with a console.log (html) header is automatically changed to charset = ISO-8859-1, and displays the body with special replacement characters �.

**html original page**

[image]

**console.log(html) from request method**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it isn't already utf8 and that it Is the program you are using to view the log that is the problem? Meaning the discrepancy might be because the command line/terminal window, or document viewer you are using to view the console log is not set to use utf8

Comment: maybe var $ = cheerio.load(html, { decodeEntities: false });

Comment: @PatrickEvans The original page I am scraping has header charset = utf-8, but when I use the request (url, response, html) method. This html when I show it with a console.log (html) header is automatically changed to charset = ISO-8859-1, and displays the body with special replacement characters �. See the images in the edit post please, thanks